# Azure DevOps keep NLog configuration on Release, when Nuget Packaging updates

Tags: azure-devops, nlog

I am trying to keep my NLog configurations, when I do a release from Azure Devops.  The Nuget Package portion overwrites my NLog configurations and sets it back to default.  I would like to know how to preserve my configurations when I release my build, but keep the Nuget Packages update to date for the other packages.

Comment: Remember not to use `NLog.config`-nuget package. It is a trap, that causes your NLog.config to be overwritten by a blank version

Comment: If not using https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config then make sure that you have enabled the `NLog.config` to also be included in publish. Make sure to enable `CopyToPublishDirectory` for the NLog.config in your csproj-file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the NLog.Config package for that.

It's documented here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config

> Note: Unfortunately this package won't work well when using
>
> Advised to:
>
> - download manually: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NLog/NLog/dev/src/NuGet/NLog.Config/content/NLog.config
> - set "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy if newer"